IAudioCaptureClient::GetBuffer() returns AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT before user logon
I want to capture audio in my Windows app using WinAPI (specifically IAudioCaptureClient::GetBuffer method) without the user logging on the machine (i.e. with the app running as a service).
This works completely fine when the user is logged on.
However, if I run my application as a service without any prior user logon, this method is returning AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT (Treat all of the data in the packet as silence and ignore the actual data values... see here)
Exactly at the moment of the user logon, this error disappears, and the audio is captured correctly (even if the user logs off)!
How can I avoid this silence error meanwhile the user never logged on?
What I tried: Asked ChatGPT; tried disabling Microphone Exclusive mode, changing power settings, registry settings or Task Scheduler hacks

This sounds like intentional behaviour.

So, what could I do to work around it?

It's weird that such an API would work without a logged in user. This would compromise privacy because the PC would be able to record without a user noticing - and something tells me that's your intention.
